How to get the same output in mathabx package?
The output in the package documentation looks like 
My output looks like this

The package output looks like it has lower resolution or some other modification while mine looks smooth.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}


\usepackage{mathabx}



\begin{document}
    Check
        \begin{align*}
            \sum_{n\leq x}\prod_{n\leq x}\\
            \left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)
                & = \binom{a}{b}
        \end{align*}


\end{document}

Source of the pdf from which I took the screenshot: https://pastecode.io/s/tf33i7th
Source of testmac.tex required for this:
https://pastecode.io/s/3zok4acx

Why don't you show the same formula, pointing to the part that you do not get as in the documentation? As it is now, we can only guess...

If I had the formula, I would simply use that directly. The output is taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mathabx/mathtest.pdf which is why I linked to the package documentation. The source is there but it does not compile properly. But since you point it out, I will update the question with the source the package comes with.

What is the problem? To rewrite first formula in LaTeX?

Are they being viewed in the same browser? And even if they are different, surely you're not interested in the lower-quality version being displayed by the documentation, right? So is the larger question: Why are they different?

Yes, but it turns out the issue is different.

The manual of mathabx was written when the fonts weren’t available in (scalable) Type1 format, but only in bitmap format, with poor conversion to PDF.
You’re using the Type1 version: be glad and don’t complain the something got better.
